# Change Bottom tab navigator data dynamically from component React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

Basically my idea is to display notifications count in my bottom tab navigator like this picture [image]

For now i'm displaying those numbers statically, and i've created an Icon component that helps me to insert the count number as props parameter, this is my navigation file :

```
const mainStack = createStackNavigator(
{
    Home,
    NewPost,
    PostDetail
},
{
    defaultNavigationOptions: defaultNavigationOptions,
    headerBackTitleVisible: false
}
);

const mainTab = createBottomTabNavigator(
{
    Home: mainStack,  
    Invitations: Invitations,  
    Messages: Messages,
    Notifications: Notifications,  
    Cards: Cards,  
},
{
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation, screenProps }) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
          const { routeName } = navigation.state;
          let iconName;
          if (routeName === 'Home') {
            iconName = focused ? 'home': 'home-outline';
          } else if (routeName === 'Invitations') {
            iconName = focused ? 'people' : 'people-outline';
          }else if (routeName === 'Messages'){
            iconName = focused ? 'chatbubbles' : 'chatbubbles-outline';
          }else if (routeName === 'Notifications'){
            iconName = focused ? 'notifications' : 'notifications-outline';
          }else if (routeName === 'Cards'){
            return  <FontAwesome5 name={"id-card"} size={24} color={colors.GREEN} solid={iconName = focused}/>
          }
          // You can return any component that you like here!
          return <TabIcon iconName={iconName} data={screenProps} count='3'/>;
        },
    }),
    headerBackTitleVisible: false,
}
);

  const switcher = createSwitchNavigator(
      {
          Reception: Reception,
          Auth: authStack,
          Main: mainTab,
      },
      {
       initialRouteName: 'Reception',
       defaultNavigationOptions: defaultNavigationOptions
     }
   );



  export default createAppContainer(switcher);
```

And then i'm calling this navigator in my main `index.js` like te following :

```
const AppWrapper = () => {
   return <Root><Navigation /></Root>
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent(name, () => AppWrapper);
```

I do have a backend endpoint that fetch all notifications counts , i'm really confused though about where and when to call it, i tried to call it when my home component mount ( bcz it is basically the first component that mount when the app opens )
so in my home component i did this

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.loadStats();
}

loadStats = async () => {
    let stats = await getStats();
}
```

And then i really don't know how to pass this stats from my home component to the navigator ending to my tabIcon component. is there a built in function for that ?
Also i do have a socket connection so this counts can change on real time is there a good way to do that ??

Answer (score 0):

It would be handy to have more code available to see how to solve your problem.
With whats given I can give a few recommendations:

1. you need to store the stats in your locaState:

   loadStats = async () => {
   const stats = await getStats();
   this.setState({
   stats
   });
   };
2. You need to pass the state down to your Navigator component.
   !I dont know where your Navigator component ist, but if its inside your Home components you would need to do something like this:

   ```
    render() {
      return (
         <>
           <Navigator stats={this.state.stats} />         
         </>    
      )}
   ```
3. Inside your Navigator component you need to take the stats from your props and pass them to your TabIcon component

   ```
    render() {
      return (
         <>
           <TabIcon stats={this.props.stats} />         
         </>    
      )}
   ```

I hope this helps. In general you need to look at state managementin React to understand how to do these things

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i've edited my post and tried to display all my navigation code, because i think in my case the home is the child of the navigator not the opposite no ? or at least that what i think